# Google Play Console. Сбой при загрузке Не удалось сохранить изменения. Повторите попытку. ЗАГРУЗИТЬ ДРУГОЙ ФАЙЛ APK

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-console

[image: Сбой при загрузке]

СЛУЧИЛОСЬ СТРАШНОЕ!!!

Историю, куки и все такое чистил. Пробовал в Chrome, Yandex, Opera. Режим Инкогнито пробовал. Ранее, в течение года ничего подобного не было...

Comment: Наверное вы случайно включили подпись приложения гуглом и подписывать файл теперь надо иначе

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Решение. Вышел из Google Play Console... И опять зашел (введя имя, пароль)...

И все заработало!!!

При этом, банально, произошло обновление сессии (не только у клиента (чистка куки, кэша, истории и т.п.), но и на сервере все обновилось... И все заработало... )

Т.е. "чистка" только у себя далеко не всегда помогает!!!

Comment: Это исчерпывающий и четкий ответ. В течение трех дней перепробовал кучу вариантов, даже обращался в поддержку... И только вот это краткое и конкретное решение помогло!

Comment: Спасибо, чувак!

Comment: У себя ничего не чистил, просто перезашел.